# Symfony 3.4 ldap authentication issue

Tags: symfony, ldap, symfony-3.4

I am trying to authenticate users through ldap (window active directory) with Symfony 3.4 and i use this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/ldap.html)

Please, Help Me!!!!

But I'm getting error:

> php.DEBUG: Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\SilencedErrorContext: {\"severity\":2,\"file\":\"C:\\OSPanel\\domains\\warcsymfony\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\Adapter\\ExtLdap\\Connection.php\",\"line\":53,\"trace\":[{\"file\":\"C:\\OSPanel\\domains\\warcsymfony\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\Ldap.php\",\"line\":38,\"function\":\"bind\",\"class\":\"Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\Adapter\\ExtLdap\\Connection\",\"type\":\"->\"}],\"count\":1})"} []
>   [2018-03-14 10:27:03] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at C:\OSPanel\domains\warcsymfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php:71, Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException(code: 0): User \"testusername\" not found. at C:\OSPanel\domains\warcsymfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\LdapUserProvider.php:75, Symfony\Component\Ldap\Exception\ConnectionException(code: 0): Invalid credentials at C:\OSPanel\domains\warcsymfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Connection.php:54)"} []
>   [2018-03-14 10:27:03] security.DEBUG: Authentication failure, redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"login"} []

I tried change in parameters, but it did not work

```
security.yml

security:

  providers:
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: DC=example,DC=com
            search_dn: 'OU=all-users-accounts,DC=example,DC=com'
            search_password: password
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: sAMAccountName
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: 'sAMAccountName={username},DC=example,DC=com'

service.yml
services:
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
        arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
        arguments:
            -   host: **.**.**.**
                port: 389
                encryption: 'none'
                options:
                    protocol_version: 3
                    referrals: false
```

SecurityController

```
 /**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils){

    $error  = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $username = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $username,
        'error' => $error
        ));
}
```

Comment: ,DC=example,DC=example'
last DC in search_dn line should be DC=com

Comment: @Agris it's not working, I did everything right. search_dn line is just example.

Answer (score 1):

So tested and work. i think what your mistake was search_dn,search_password and query_string.

```
my_ldap:
      ldap:
          service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
          base_dn: "DC=example,DC=lv"
          #remmber this is ldap user with read only permisions
          #could be also just username search_dn:"bind"
          search_dn: "CN=bind bind,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=lv"
          search_password: "bind user password"
          uid_key: sAMAccountName
```

in form example i used query string- it check if sAMAccoutName and if member of SystemGroup.

```
form_login_ldap:
                provider:  my_ldap
                login_path: login_route
                check_path: login_check_form
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                dn_string: 'DC=example,DC=lv'
                query_string: '(&(sAMAccountName={username})(memberof=CN=SystemGroup,OU=Groups,OU=xxx_users,DC=example,DC=lv))'
```

Just test your query_string with ldap_search
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php#112191

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is your search_dn which is incorrect, this line:

```
search_dn: 'OU=all-users-accounts,DC=example,DC=com'
```

It needs to be the dn of the administrator that has access to browse Active Directory. You can use [Softerra's free LDAP Browser](http://www.ldapadministrator.com/download.htm) to browse active directory and figure that out.

This is all outlined in my [Symfony LDAP Component AD Authentication](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2017/09/07/symfony-ldap-component-ad-authentication/) article. Be advised, you need to do a lot of debugging to get this working, but once you get it working it's easy.

Comment: I just need to ldap_bind(), I do not need to read user information, just checking the username and password. I tested native code without symfony ldap component and it work.

Comment: The Symfony LDAP component requires an admin account that can read AD.

Comment: I can't open your Link:https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2017/09/07/symfony-ldap-component-ad-authentication/

Comment: The link works fine for me! Just click on it on this post directly.